# Safari and window.open() -- how to use it and not get focus?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, cross-browser

My order entry web site is being enhanced to have a Master / Child window architecture. The Child windows would be used for "by the way..." searches and the Master window is where editing occurs. Periodically the Master window wants to tell things to the Child windows.  If it has a handle to the child, such as that from window.open(), then this is easy.

Because the user might refresh the Master window (F5) the page must recover its list of children.  I don't know of a way of doing this apart from going through a list of likely child window names using window.open().  Tests of this idea on my computer running Windows, with the Chrome / Firefox / MSIE browsers, all work OK.

However, I don't get good Safari results. When run on a variety of Mac OS / Safari versions calling window.open() always also brings that window to the foreground.  To me this is deal-breaking behavior.  *Running window.open() then window.blur() isn't acceptable due to the flash display of the undesired window.*

**Question:** Is there a way of calling window.open() (and not window.blur()) while always suppressing the "bring to foreground" behavior?

**Question:** Are there ways of getting a window handle w/o using window.open()?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

window.opener would be the answer for your question. But window.opener is not supported by IE. 
something like below would help.

```
if ($.browser.safari)
 std = window.opener("", "childwindowname");
else
 std = window.open("", "childwindowname");
```

Comment: At work a coworker answered this with "window.opener.somefunc(window);".  When the child is opened it calls its opener and tells that context that it has a child.  It keeps a list of children.  My site has complex behavior, where users might navigate the parent window to another page in the site.  The children will periodically ping the parent (the parent:child relationship persists for windows no matter the content) to relieve its amnesia about its children.  This is working so far.  I'd add this as a separate answer, but the SO keepers ding me for "off-topic replies".